# JavaScript print() without URL and Date

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, safari, browser

I made a little "CMS" for writing, managing and printing bills for a company. The bills are saved on the server as HTML-files. The javascript code is `document.billFrame.print();`. Is it possible to prevent the browser of printing the URL and date? Because I know that it's probably not possible with JavaScript/CSS, is it possible to install a browser-Plugin or something like that for Safari/Chrome or FF? The CMS will be only used on one computer, so it doesn't matter if a plugin is required.

Thanks for help

Comment: I think you can't do that with JavaScript, however the user can disable these things before printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox:

Print -> Page Setup -> Margins & Headers/Footers

In Chrome:

Print -> Uncheck Headers and Footers under Options

Comment: Cool, pretty easy in Chrome. Didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The header you're seeing is coming from your browser, not the page you're `print()`ing, so opening up  new window and stying it with JS/CSS won't work.

Manage these settings via your browser preferences. [Howto here](http://www.mintprintables.com/print-tips/header-footer-windows/) for each major browser.